# Что делает программа

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю, что выводит данная программа

```
x = int(input())
L = 94
M = 0
while L >= x:
  M = M + 1
  L = L - x
if M < L:
  x = M
  M = L
  L = x
print(L)
print(M)
```

Comment: Вот объясню я вам, а вы потом опять мой ответ не примите. Зачем мне тогда стараться?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я не знал что надо что то принимать

Answer (score 3):

```
x = int(input())   # Запрашиваем у пользователя число (у вас тут опечатка)
L = 94             # Объявлением переменную L равную 94 (с нарушением PEP8)
M = 0              # Объявлением переменную M равную 0 (тоже с нарушением PEP8)
while L >= x:      # Пока L больше или равна x
  M = M + 1        # Увеличиваем значение M на 1
  L = L - x        # Уменьшаем значение L на x
if M < L:          # Если M меньше L
  x = M            # Присваиваем переменной x значение переменной M
  M = L            # Присваиваем переменной M значение переменной L
  L = x            # Присваиваем переменной L значение переменной x
print(L)           # Выводим L
print(M)           # Выводим M
```

Comment: нет, это я понимаю, может я некорректно спросил, но мне нужно знать, что она выводит, это задача из задачника по ЕГЭ и чтобы решить ее, мне нужно знать, что вообще эта программа делает

Comment: нужно , чтобы она выводила сначала 3 , потом 7 при наименьшем Х, но я не могу понять как мне сузить круг поиска, не перебирать же 94 числа

Comment: Как и положено учебным программам, ничего полезного. Вводите 29.